# Remove all punctuation from string

Tags: python, pandas, string

I am currently working on a pandas dataframe and trying to extract the value from the column that consists of a string within a list, but I am kinda stuck on how to only keep the text I want.

This is how one of list looks like:

```
["{'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards': 'True'",
 "'RestaurantsPriceRange2': '2'",
 "'ByAppointmentOnly': 'False'",
 "'BikeParking': 'False'",
 '\'BusinessParking\': "{\'garage\': False',
 "'street': True",
 "'validated': False",
 "'lot': False",
 '\'valet\': False}"}']
```

On the left of the colon, it is the attribute and on the right of the colon, it is the corresponding value.  Is there a way for me to go over this list and get rid of all the punctuations in each string and obtain the text only for both the attribute and the corresponding value?

So my idea is to first break with the colon by using the following code:

```
txt = df_business['attributes'][2]
y = txt.split(", ")
y
y1 = y[0].split(":")
y1
y1[1].strip()
```

But with the code I have above, I am only able to get the following result:

```
Attribute = "{'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards'"
Value = "'True'"
```

The result I want is:

```
Attribute = "BusinessAcceptsCreditCards"
Value = "True"
```

Example of the dataframe:

```json
{'business_id': {0: '6iYb2HFDywm3zjuRg0shjw',
  1: 'tCbdrRPZA0oiIYSmHG3J0w',
  2: 'bvN78flM8NLprQ1a1y5dRg',
  3: 'oaepsyvc0J17qwi8cfrOWg',
  4: 'PE9uqAjdw0E4-8mjGl3wVA',
  5: 'D4JtQNTI4X3KcbzacDJsMw',
  6: 't35jsh9YnMtttm69UCp7gw',
  7: 'jFYIsSb7r1QeESVUnXPHBw',
  8: 'N3_Gs3DnX4k9SgpwJxdEfw'},
 'name': {0: 'Oskar Blues Taproom',
  1: 'Flying Elephants at PDX',
  2: 'The Reclaimory',
  3: 'Great Clips',
  4: 'Crossfit Terminus',
  5: 'Bob Likes Thai Food',
  6: 'Escott Orthodontics',
  7: 'Boxwood Biscuit',
  8: 'Lane Wells Jewelry Repair'},
 'address': {0: '921 Pearl St',
  1: '7000 NE Airport Way',
  2: '4720 Hawthorne Ave',
  3: '2566 Enterprise Rd',
  4: '1046 Memorial Dr SE',
  5: '3755 Main St',
  6: '2511 Edgewater Dr',
  7: '740 S High St',
  8: '7801 N Lamar Blvd, Ste A140'},
 'city': {0: 'Boulder',
  1: 'Portland',
  2: 'Portland',
  3: 'Orange City',
  4: 'Atlanta',
  5: 'Vancouver',
  6: 'Orlando',
  7: 'Columbus',
  8: 'Austin'},
 'state': {0: 'CO',
  1: 'OR',
  2: 'OR',
  3: 'FL',
  4: 'GA',
  5: 'BC',
  6: 'FL',
  7: 'OH',
  8: 'TX'},
 'postal_code': {0: '80302',
  1: '97218',
  2: '97214',
  3: '32763',
  4: '30316',
  5: 'V5V',
  6: '32804',
  7: '43206',
  8: '78752'},
 'latitude': {0: 40.0175444,
  1: 45.5889058992,
  2: 45.5119069956,
  3: 28.9144823,
  4: 33.7470274,
  5: 49.2513423,
  6: 28.573998,
  7: 39.947006523,
  8: 30.346169},
 'longitude': {0: -105.2833481,
  1: -122.5933307507,
  2: -122.6136928797,
  3: -81.2959787,
  4: -84.3534244,
  5: -123.101333,
  6: -81.3892841,
  7: -82.997471,
  8: -97.711458},
 'stars': {0: 4.0,
  1: 4.0,
  2: 4.5,
  3: 3.0,
  4: 4.0,
  5: 3.5,
  6: 4.5,
  7: 4.5,
  8: 5.0},
 'review_count': {0: 86,
  1: 126,
  2: 13,
  3: 8,
  4: 14,
  5: 169,
  6: 7,
  7: 11,
  8: 30},
 'is_open': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1, 8: 1},
 'attributes': {0: '{\'RestaurantsTableService\': \'True\', \'WiFi\': "u\'free\'", \'BikeParking\': \'True\', \'BusinessParking\': "{\'garage\': False, \'street\': True, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': False, \'valet\': False}", \'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsReservations\': \'False\', \'WheelchairAccessible\': \'True\', \'Caters\': \'True\', \'OutdoorSeating\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsGoodForGroups\': \'True\', \'HappyHour\': \'True\', \'BusinessAcceptsBitcoin\': \'False\', \'RestaurantsPriceRange2\': \'2\', \'Ambience\': "{\'touristy\': False, \'hipster\': False, \'romantic\': False, \'divey\': False, \'intimate\': False, \'trendy\': False, \'upscale\': False, \'classy\': False, \'casual\': True}", \'HasTV\': \'True\', \'Alcohol\': "\'beer_and_wine\'", \'GoodForMeal\': "{\'dessert\': False, \'latenight\': False, \'lunch\': False, \'dinner\': False, \'brunch\': False, \'breakfast\': False}", \'DogsAllowed\': \'False\', \'RestaurantsTakeOut\': \'True\', \'NoiseLevel\': "u\'average\'", \'RestaurantsAttire\': "\'casual\'", \'RestaurantsDelivery\': \'None\'}',
  1: '{\'RestaurantsTakeOut\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsAttire\': "u\'casual\'", \'GoodForKids\': \'True\', \'BikeParking\': \'False\', \'OutdoorSeating\': \'False\', \'Ambience\': "{\'romantic\': False, \'intimate\': False, \'touristy\': False, \'hipster\': False, \'divey\': False, \'classy\': False, \'trendy\': False, \'upscale\': False, \'casual\': True}", \'Caters\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsReservations\': \'False\', \'RestaurantsDelivery\': \'False\', \'HasTV\': \'False\', \'RestaurantsGoodForGroups\': \'False\', \'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards\': \'True\', \'NoiseLevel\': "u\'average\'", \'ByAppointmentOnly\': \'False\', \'RestaurantsPriceRange2\': \'2\', \'WiFi\': "u\'free\'", \'BusinessParking\': "{\'garage\': True, \'street\': False, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': False, \'valet\': False}", \'Alcohol\': "u\'beer_and_wine\'", \'GoodForMeal\': "{\'dessert\': False, \'latenight\': False, \'lunch\': True, \'dinner\': False, \'brunch\': False, \'breakfast\': True}"}',
  2: '{\'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsPriceRange2\': \'2\', \'ByAppointmentOnly\': \'False\', \'BikeParking\': \'False\', \'BusinessParking\': "{\'garage\': False, \'street\': True, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': False, \'valet\': False}"}',
  3: "{'RestaurantsPriceRange2': '1', 'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards': 'True', 'GoodForKids': 'True', 'ByAppointmentOnly': 'False'}",
  4: '{\'GoodForKids\': \'False\', \'BusinessParking\': "{\'garage\': False, \'street\': False, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': False, \'valet\': False}", \'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards\': \'True\'}',
  5: '{\'GoodForKids\': \'True\', \'Alcohol\': "u\'none\'", \'RestaurantsGoodForGroups\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsReservations\': \'True\', \'BusinessParking\': "{\'garage\': False, \'street\': True, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': False, \'valet\': False}", \'RestaurantsAttire\': "u\'casual\'", \'BikeParking\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsPriceRange2\': \'2\', \'HasTV\': \'False\', \'NoiseLevel\': "u\'average\'", \'WiFi\': "u\'no\'", \'RestaurantsTakeOut\': \'True\', \'Caters\': \'False\', \'OutdoorSeating\': \'False\', \'Ambience\': "{\'romantic\': False, \'intimate\': False, \'classy\': False, \'hipster\': False, \'divey\': False, \'touristy\': False, \'trendy\': False, \'upscale\': False, \'casual\': True}", \'GoodForMeal\': "{\'dessert\': False, \'latenight\': False, \'lunch\': True, \'dinner\': True, \'brunch\': False, \'breakfast\': False}", \'DogsAllowed\': \'False\', \'RestaurantsDelivery\': \'True\'}',
  6: "{'AcceptsInsurance': 'True', 'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards': 'True', 'ByAppointmentOnly': 'True'}",
  7: nan,
  8: '{\'RestaurantsPriceRange2\': \'1\', \'ByAppointmentOnly\': \'False\', \'BusinessParking\': "{\'garage\': False, \'street\': False, \'validated\': False, \'lot\': True, \'valet\': False}", \'BusinessAcceptsCreditCards\': \'True\', \'DogsAllowed\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsDelivery\': \'None\', \'BusinessAcceptsBitcoin\': \'False\', \'BikeParking\': \'True\', \'RestaurantsTakeOut\': \'None\', \'WheelchairAccessible\': \'True\'}'},
 'categories': {0: 'Gastropubs, Food, Beer Gardens, Restaurants, Bars, American (Traditional), Beer Bar, Nightlife, Breweries',
  1: 'Salad, Soup, Sandwiches, Delis, Restaurants, Cafes, Vegetarian',
  2: 'Antiques, Fashion, Used, Vintage & Consignment, Shopping, Furniture Stores, Home & Garden',
  3: 'Beauty & Spas, Hair Salons',
  4: 'Gyms, Active Life, Interval Training Gyms, Fitness & Instruction',
  5: 'Restaurants, Thai',
  6: 'Dentists, Health & Medical, Orthodontists',
  7: 'Breakfast & Brunch, Restaurants',
  8: 'Shopping, Jewelry Repair, Appraisal Services, Local Services, Jewelry, Engraving, Gold Buyers'},
 'hours': {0: "{'Monday': '11:0-23:0', 'Tuesday': '11:0-23:0', 'Wednesday': '11:0-23:0', 'Thursday': '11:0-23:0', 'Friday': '11:0-23:0', 'Saturday': '11:0-23:0', 'Sunday': '11:0-23:0'}",
  1: "{'Monday': '5:0-18:0', 'Tuesday': '5:0-17:0', 'Wednesday': '5:0-18:0', 'Thursday': '5:0-18:0', 'Friday': '5:0-18:0', 'Saturday': '5:0-18:0', 'Sunday': '5:0-18:0'}",
  2: "{'Thursday': '11:0-18:0', 'Friday': '11:0-18:0', 'Saturday': '11:0-18:0', 'Sunday': '11:0-18:0'}",
  3: nan,
  4: "{'Monday': '16:0-19:0', 'Tuesday': '16:0-19:0', 'Wednesday': '16:0-19:0', 'Thursday': '16:0-19:0', 'Friday': '16:0-19:0', 'Saturday': '9:0-11:0'}",
  5: "{'Monday': '17:0-21:0', 'Tuesday': '17:0-21:0', 'Wednesday': '17:0-21:0', 'Thursday': '17:0-21:0', 'Friday': '17:0-21:0', 'Saturday': '17:0-21:0', 'Sunday': '17:0-21:0'}",
  6: "{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-17:30', 'Wednesday': '8:0-17:30', 'Thursday': '8:0-17:30', 'Friday': '8:0-17:30'}",
  7: "{'Saturday': '8:0-14:0', 'Sunday': '8:0-14:0'}",
  8: "{'Monday': '12:15-17:0', 'Tuesday': '12:15-17:0', 'Wednesday': '12:15-17:0', 'Thursday': '12:15-17:0', 'Friday': '12:15-17:0'}"}}
```

Comment: Have you try to parse the original data as JSON?
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

Comment: please provide an example of the dataframe itself and the expected output

Comment: @mozway What is the best way for me to provide an example of the dataframe?

Comment: @DJ-coding e.g., like [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/display-the-pandas-dataframe-in-table-style/)

Comment: @DJ-coding: `df.head().to_dict()` and paste the output in your question

Comment: @cg-zhou The file was in JSON and I converted it into a csv file then created a data frame for it.

Comment: @mozway Just updated the example of the dataframe to the post.

Comment: @DJ-coding now please provide the expected output (e.g. for the first row) ;)

Comment: @mozway What I want is to count the number of times that True and False shows up in each restaurant attribute, so I should have two columns while one counts for True and one count for False, and ignore that attribute that doesn't have a value as True or False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I want to count the number of time that True and False shows up in each restaurant attribute*

You can concatenate all elements of you list and search for the `'\bTrue\b'` /`'\bFalse\b'` patterns (`\b` denotes word boundaries):

```
s = df['attributes'].fillna('').apply(''.join)
df['nb_True'] = s.str.count(r'\bTrue\b')
df['nb_False'] = s.str.count(r'\bFalse\b')
```

output:

```
>>> df[['nb_True', 'nb_False']]
   nb_True  nb_False
0       12        21
1        8        23
2        2         6
3        2         1
4        1         6
5       10        20
6        3         0
7        0         0
8        5         6
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried to run the code above but it is returning a table with all counts as zero... another problem that I realized that is the table actually consist of some NaN value, so I turned them into an empty string, could that be one of the reasons that I am getting this result?

Comment: @DJ-coding this works with the sample you provided, can you update it with problematic rows?

Comment: I just updated the data frame and row 8 the row that has NaN for the attribute.  Thanks!

Comment: @DJ-coding check the update, I added a `fillna('')` step

Comment: For some reason, I used the exact code from above and the same data frame and I still keep getting 0 counts for all of them... When you convert the dictionary into data frame did you use this "df = pd.DataFrame(dic)" ?

Comment: @DJ-coding yes I did

Comment: I found that the reason that causes the counts for True and False to be zero is the use of "\b".  Turns out "df['nb_True'] = s.str.count('True')" worked for me, I checked the documentation and it said that "\b is used to match the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word."  If that is the case, I am wondering why using \b worked for you but not me?

Comment: @DJ-coding try the update, I forgot the raw string: `r'\b...'`